# How to replace double quoutes with brackets?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find every word that is double quoted and replace the qoutes into brackets, because perl finds syntax error by executing the string in sybase iq, if there are double qoutes in the code. Example:

```
"test", "default", "left","right"
```

i want to replace to look like this

```
[test], [default], [left],[right]
```

this is how far i come:

```
 $arr_tab[$i] =~ s/"\w+"/[$0]/g;
```

The `\w+`  finds all the "words" in the string and replaces it with `[test]`, im not sure how to write the finding into `$0` and iterrate trough it so it makes the proper replace for every find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use capturing groups and also use `[^"]` to match any character but not of `"`, if you use `\w`, it would match only the word characters and it won't work if there is a non-word character present inside the double quotes.

```
s/"([^"]*)"/[$1]/g;
```

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = '"test", "default", "left","right"';
$string =~ s/"([^"]*)"/[$1]/g;
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
[test], [default], [left],[right]
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job that would suit [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords), a core module in Perl 5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print join ", ", map "[$_]", quotewords('\s*,\s*',0,$_);
}

__DATA__
"test", "default", "left","right"
```

Output is:

```
[test], [default], [left], [right]
```

Explanation:

The `quotewords` subroutine parses the string, and splitting it on comma with optional surrounding whitespace. It also removes quotes, because I set the "keep" option to zero `0`. We can then use a `map` statement to apply the brackets to the resulting list of words. Finally we join it back together with commas and print.